# Long to Wide format: dcast does not conserve values (just aggregates)

Tags: r, format, reshape2

I have a dataset containing some lab measures that I need to transform to wide format:

```
Type        SpellNo SourceUniqueID RiskIndex MeasureCode NumericResult
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2       TMPRT          36.1
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2    HEART_HR          63.0
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2       RESPR          19.0
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2        AVPU            NA
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2       O2SAT          98.0
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2       FRIO2          21.0
```

Type has 2 levels (highest measure in 24h, last),

SpellNo identifies the event,

sourceuniqueID identifies measures taken within the same test.

MeasureCode is the variable that should be divided in different columns and NumericResult the value for each variable.

In the end, I would like to have something like|:

```
Type        SpellNo SourceUniqueID RiskIndex TMPRT HEART_HR RESPR AVPU O2SAT FRIO2 
 24hrs       481/5        1161        2       36.1  63.0     19.0  NA  98.0  21.0     
Latest       481/5        1158        1       36.0  58.0     20.0  NA  97.0  21.0       
 24hrs       281/2        1100        2                 
Latest       281/2        1231        0                    
 24hrs       351/5        1313        2                 
Latest       351/5        1561        1
```

I have tried the function 'dcast' like:

```
wide.observations <- dcast(observation.data, 
SpellNo+Type+SourceUniqueID+RiskIndex ~ MeasureCode)
```

But as a result I don't get the value for each variable, just a count of how many times the variable appears in each observation:

```
SpellNo  Type  SourceUniqueID RiskIndex AVPU CONSC FRIO2 HEART_HR...
481/5   High     1161          2         1      0     1        1 ...
730/18  High     1261          2         1      0     1        1 ...
162/7   High     1295          2         1      0     1        1 ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get an issue. Can you use `dput` on a sample of the data? I copied it in using `x = read.table("clipboard", header = T)` then `dcast(x, SpellNo+Type+SourceUniqueID+RiskIndex ~ MeasureCode) ` gave me the desired result.

Comment: Ah, that actually helped. I found the issue...some of the rows had been duplicated. Thanks